# How to access data in tags in xml parsing with data inside starting and closing tag?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, domparser

I am looking for an answer where I can get the solution of getting data from the xml file from tags given in below format :-

```
<Main>
   <Item>
      <id>1</id>
      <content>Hiii this is Id 1's content.</content>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <id>2</id>
      <content>Hiii this is Id 2's content.</content>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <id>3</id>
      <content>Hiii this is Id 3's content.</content>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <id>4</id>
      <content>Hiii this is Id 4's content.</content>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <id>5</id>
      <content>Hiii this is Id 5's content.</content>
   </Item>
</Main>
```

Here what I want to do is that I want to access data depending on the ID that I am getting from the bundle. The code that I am using is given as below.

```
            try {

            InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("single_item.xml");

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();


            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();


            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");


            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                GetEementNode = nList.item(temp);

                if (GetEementNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    eElement = (Element) GetEementNode;
                    String idCheck = eElement.getElementsByTagName("id").item(temp).getTextContent();

                    if(idCheck.equals(idsgot)){

                        String informationData = eElement.getElementsByTagName("content").item(temp).getTextContent();
                        information.setText(informationData);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Here "idsgot" is the id that I am getting from the bundle. but the loop never enters even if (GetEementNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) condition can anyone tell me the solution for the same. Thanks in Advance again.

Answer (score 0):

Try a proper parser instead of writing your own code. JAXB is a very good option. It needs some setup, but once done, parsing the xml is straightforward